# Plotting average of a function

Tags: functions, averages

I plotted a function and a certain horizontal line as a benchmark.

After time t = 2 my function goes below the line, which is ok.

[image]

But I need to show when the AVERAGE of this function goes below the line. For example, it crosses the line in 2 hours but on average this rate will go below the line only after 5 hours. 
How do I plot this?

Currently, my code looks approximately like this

```
Plot[{1000, function[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Thickness[0.01]}}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Name"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an example, since we don't know what you function is,

```
f[t_] := 15 Exp[-2 t]
fav[t_] = Integrate[f[tp], {tp, 0, t}]/t

Plot[
 {f[t], fav[t]},
 {t, 0, 1},
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "Name"},
 PlotRange -> All,
 GridLines -> {t /. NSolve[fav[t] == 10, t, Reals], {10}},
 GridLinesStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Darker[Green, 3/5], Thick]},
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "f average"},
 PlotLabel -> "Average of f = " <> ToString@10 <> " at t = " <> ToString[t /. First@NSolve[fav[t] == 10, t, Reals]]
 ]
```

> (15 E^-t Sinh[t])/t

[image]